GitHub merge based on PR approval in another repository
We have a central API repository that contains OpenAPI specifications for each of our microservices. Our GitHub workflow requires two approvals on all pull requests.
Currently, when we update an API spec, we create two pull requests: one for the updated API spec and another for the corresponding microservice changes.
I would like to automate the creation of the pull request for the API spec when there are changes to the relevant microservice's spec (the specs are identical copies).
Is there a way to make one pull request dependent on the approval of another pull request in a different repository in GitHub?
I tried using GitHub Workflows to enforce this, but I need to block the merge button until the dependent pull request is approved, rather than just failing the merge in the workflow after the merge button is clicked.
How can I configure GitHub to block the merge button until the required pull request is approved?

I don't think you can make what happens in one repo depend directly on what happens in another repo. This is probably just a matter of human engineering.

You can use a draft pr which blocks merging.  It may not run any automation until draft status is removed though

You could have a workflow triggered on pull_request that checks for the existence of that other PR, and make the check required in branch protections / repository rules.
